Does a SMART (long) test wear out an SSD?
Does a SMART long test do a lot of writes to SSDs and wear them out faster? I think on HDDs it includes write tests that one would like to avoid on SSDs.
For mechanical hard drives there is an answer here but for the long test the answer cites:

Long/extended A longer and more thorough version of the short self-test, scanning the entire disk surface with no time limit. This test usually takes several hours, depending on the read/write speed of the drive and its size.

That does not answer the question for SSDs, as it does not state if there is a write test for each sector involved or not. And the summary

Yes, albeit marginally. Any action that results in mechanical motion is an action that is helping the system die.

Might be different for SSDs, as there is no mechanical load on the SSD, but writing it leads to more wear than writing a HDD.

No; Most SSDs lifetime writes are multiple PB. The amount of data written during one of those tests would be a fraction of a fraction of a single percent of the lifetime writes of a SSD.

You will replace your computer before your SSD wears out

The SMART Extended (aka long) (as well as the Short) test only perform read operations. There are no write operations performed during the SMART tests. It's non-destructive. SSD (i.e. NAND flash) wear out due to performing erase+write cycles. The erase operation is required before a write operation can be performed.

@Keltari, hardly true. There have been cases of the OS destroying SSD's, e.g., https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know .

@Keltari As far as I know the terabyte written limits for consumer SSDs are about 500TB. When a long test would write each cell of a 2TB SSD, it would be a relevant number.

@sawdust If you make it an answer I can upvote it. It would be good if you could link to a source for the test being read-only, because that's the main point of the question.
